# File does not show on click if on server

Tags: php, pdf

I have an upload button on my localhost, i have this link/button

the link is the file name. for example,

```
$row[] = '<a href = "'.$info->PATH.'" class = "btn btn-sm btn-info pull-left fa  fa-question-circle" title="Show File">&nbsp Show File</a>
```

and `$info->PATH` for example is, `http://localhost/TLC_HR/uploads/pdf/sample.pdf`

when I click it, it works fine in my localhost

but when I uploaded to my server, the `$info->PATH` becomes  `http://123.123.123.123/TLC_HR/uploads/pdf/sample.pdf` (not the real address)

now, when I click this button, the file now downloads instead of showing the file. why was it? all I need to do is to just show the file.

Comment: what is the value of $info?

Comment: try setting header Content-Disposition to inline

Comment: @AmitRajput $info->PATH is the link its bec its from a foreach table.

Comment: what is the output of var_dump($info);

Answer (score 0):

try

```
<a href="#" class = "btn btn-sm btn-info pull-left fa  fa-question-circle" title="Show File" onclick="window.open('yout-pdf-url.pdf', '_blank', 'fullscreen=yes'); return false;">&nbsp Show File</a>
```

Comment: how do i give the link of the file

Comment: use current url  $info->PATH

Answer (score 0):

It is because of the headers your server is sending.

If the server sends

> Content-Disposition: Attachment, then downloading is the right thing
>   to to

. If the server sends

> Content-Disposition: Inline, then displaying is the right thing to to

Add Content-Disposition: Inline in your server configuration 
.

Comment: on what file can i find this content-disposition

Comment: Check this link
http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/124137/change-apache-httpd-server-http-header

Or you can simple read the content of that file in a veriable, use ob_clean(), Set these headers in your php code, echo content, use ob_flush

Answer (score 0):

As @Satyapal Sharma said probably is a matter of headers, my suggestion is to point your url to a php page that will handle the visualization of pdf, something like this:

```
$row[] = '<a href = "handler.php" class = "btn btn-sm btn-info pull-left fa  fa-question-circle" title="Show File">&nbsp Show File</a>
```

then in `handler.php`:

```
<?php
  // retrieve your info ecc.
  $url = $info->PATH;
  $filename = 'something.pdf'
  header('Content-type: application/pdf');
  header('Content-Disposition: inline; filename="' . $filename. '"');
  header('Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary');
  header('Accept-Ranges: bytes');
  @readfile($url);
?>
```

Comment: $url contains the filename

Comment: then just use url as filename. it was just an example :)

Comment: this worked on localhost. it showed pdf background bat have a message saying `Failed to load PDF document` why is it?

Comment: no, its good. but it took so long to load then it said failed to load pdf. haha